# Prevent UIViews from overlapping

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit

I'm trying to implement a doughnut diagram, but I'm struggling in keeping the tags from overlapping each other. I'm looking for ideas on clean solutions to avoid this.

The segment and tag class looks as such:

```
class Segment {
    var index: Double?
    var tagText: String?
}

class SegmentTag: UIView {
    @IBOutlet var iconView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var textLabel: UILabel!

    init(text: String?, icon: UIImage?, frame: CGRect) {
        ...
    }
}
```

In the diagram class, the segments and tags are drawn in draw(_ rect:):

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    for tag in tags {
        tag.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    tags = [UIView]()

    let tagSize = CGSize(width: 50, height: 60)

    for segment in segments {
        // ... Draw each segment
        let radius = ...
        let angle = ...
        let tag = SegmentTag(text: segment.tagText, icon: tagIcon, frame: tagRect)
        var tagPoint = CGPoint(x: radius * cos(angle),
                               y: radius * sin(angle))
        var tagRect = CGRect(origin: tagPoint, size: tagSize)
        self.addSubview(tag)
        tags.append(tag)
    }
}
```

[image: Colliding tags]

How would you go about avoiding the views from overlapping?

Comment: I had faced a similar issue, you can mitigate the problem by varying the length of the lines. However you would still run into the same issue when you have a large number of smaller values clustered together. I had to ultimately implement a legend in a separate table view.

Answer (score 1):

Start by calculating all the points for your various `SegmentTag` objects and group any together than are too close to be visible.

One option after you have your objects grouped, display a different kind of tag, a `GroupTag` or something, perhaps with the count of `SegmentTag` it has inside of it, that can be tapped and brings up a popover with a list of your `SegmentTag` objects.

Another option is to use your `GroupTag` to simply look different, but show the data, for instance it wouldn't have the image, but instead a list of values.

In my opinion these are much easier and more reliable solutions than actually calculating non-overlapping locations for all possible data sets.